# remove magento cart item product link using product ID

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to prevent one specific product from linking back to itsproduct page from the magento cart.

This is what I've tried but it still generates the link:

```
<?php $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId(); ?>

<?php if ($this->hasProductUrl() && $this->product_id != '387'):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
 <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've used `$this->product_id`, you should just have used `$product_id`, ie;

```
 <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl() && $product_id != '387'):?>
```